Vivado 2018.3 generate bitstream consume a lot of time
I am using Vivado 2018.3(on Ubuntu 22.04) and my project is about pcie xdma,not very big project.
The syn and implementation part takes about 5 minutes , and it report time failed.
But I want to generate bitstream anyhow. It takes nearely 1-2 hour to generate it, and system monitor shows cpu cores and memory almost didn't work with big load(cpu 5%,memory 30%),that's wierd!
Some try:
1.I modified the timing constraint,it helps,but when I changed my design(e.g add ILA),the time of generate bitstream still turn from 2 min to 2 hour
2.My be the version bug, I need to download another version to verify it
3.My be environment wrong with Linux, it lost some driver or lib to cause this Question

The problem have solved: I changed the version to 2019.2, and , everything get OK
